# WPF Dependency Property xaml add suggestion / option list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependencies

I have a control where i want to add CharacterCasing since it doesn't support it by default.

I added a custom dependency property called "CharacterCasing".
Now when i use it in xaml i want to have the options just like in the normal TextBox:

[image: Example how i want it to look like]

Any ideas how to implement the suggestion list in the dependency property?

This is my code in xaml:

`<TestControl:APTextBox CharacterCasing="UpperCase" Text="{Binding AktuelleZeile.LKR, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">`

And this is the dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterCasingProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(name: "CharacterCasing",
                                   propertyType: typeof(string),
                                   ownerType: typeof(APTextBox),
                                   typeMetadata: new PropertyMetadata("Normal"));

public string CharacterCasing
{
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(CharacterCasingProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(CharacterCasingProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [TextBox.CharacterCasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.charactercasing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property. Its type is [System.Windows.Controls.CharacterCasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.charactercasing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), not string. If your control is derived from TextBox, you don't need to declare such a property another time.

Comment: @Clemens Changing the type from string to CharacterCasing worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define it as string. Change the string with `CharacterCasing` or which kind of enum you want to use.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterCasingProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(name: "CharacterCasing",
                               propertyType: typeof(CharacterCasing),
                               ownerType: typeof(APTextBox),
                               typeMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(CharacterCasing.Normal));

public CharacterCasing CharacterCasing
{
    get { return (CharacterCasing)this.GetValue(CharacterCasingProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(CharacterCasingProperty, value); }
}
```